# How to analyze which methods/resources are holding a Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I've been having some trouble finding points in my code that can be improved for better parallelism. I have a pretty heavy task which I'm executing multiple times with a `ExecutorService`. However, upon making it a bit heavier(by modifying its parameters), I noticed that there is a problem where my tasks are all waiting for one of them to finish, whereas I was expecting each task to act independent from the other.

I was wondering if there is any way to analyze my code to find the points where my threads are waiting for some resource, so that I know where should I be modifying in order to improve my program's parallel performance.  The program is relatively big, so analyzing each control flow by itself would take a prohibitively long time(while also being error-prone), and I'd rather do it in a programmatic way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does your task use (potentially) parallel stream processing?

Comment: Unless there's some unexpected behavior for `Collections#stream()`, I made sure there were no `Stream#parallel()` calls for my task, but since the code base is big enough that I don't know every detail of it, having a programmatic way to find out points where the code could hang would probably help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to take few thread dumps with jstack and see where most of threads are. If that is not enough run a profiler, again simplest probably is Visual VM CPU sampler and it will tell you where each thread is spending time, including waiting. That should cover most common cases.